# Cast Action to NSAction?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monomac, xamarin.mac

I was wondering if there's a cleaner work-around for this:

```
public class Sys
{
    public static void DispatchAsync(Action action)
    {
        DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() => { action(); });
    }
}
```

This Sys class is platform-neutral, so Action should be the method parameter type, but GCD's DispatchAsync won't take action if it's an Action type, only as an NSAction or the work-around here . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `Sys`isn't platform neutral if it is using Grand Central Dispatch. Better use `Task.Run()` and `async/await`.

And no, there is no better way than your workaround.

Comment: My plan is to rewrite the class implementation depending on the OS, so Sys should be an implementation of an Interface . . .